# How to show room information if map zoom in?

Tags: android, mapbox

I used the mapbox to create a simple floor plan for the building, and I want to show some information about the room when the map is enlarged.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `FillLayer` to show polygons (e.g. the shape of rooms). `SymbolLayer`s are for icons and text (e.g. room numbers). `LineLayer`s could show the outline of the rooms.

You can add sources/layers directly to the map:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/data-driven-styling/#sources
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/data-driven-styling/#layers

There's also [the Annotation
   Plugin](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/)

There are two main ways you can have the data appear at a certain zoom level.

1. You could set min and max zoom levels for a specific layer:

   - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=setMinZoom&unscoped_q=setMinZoom
   - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=setMaxZoom&unscoped_q=setMaxZoom
2. You could use runtime styling to adjust certain layers' opacities based on zoom. This will fade the data in and out of the map as the zoom level changes.

   - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/query/RedoSearchInAreaActivity.java#L81-L84
   - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/labs/IndoorMapActivity.java#L198-L201

The two links above show `fillOpacity()`. There are equivalent  `iconOpacity()` and `textOpacity()` methods for `SymbolLayer`. `LineLayer` usage will require `lineOpacity()`.